# Randomize texture or material for several similar objects

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I want to make a scene with many fallen bricks lying around. However, all the bricks cannot have the same colour or texture. What approach can i use to make the bricks look different? Manually creating multiple materials is not an option in this case
EDIT: I'm using the cycles renderer

Comment: Blender render or cycles? With cycles there is the [object info node like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/70434/935).

Comment: cycles- I will edit the question. :)