# Fur with the new geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes, eevee-render-engine, hair

Guys is it possible to create a fluffy fur with the new geometry nodes?
I've try it and it always end up like my baby pinguin had a beard hair on it.

If some one have a tip or something I would it appreciate

[image]

Comment: there are tutorials about the new hair systems on yt....e.g. Johnny Matthews makes pretty nice and easy to undertstand tutorials

Comment: @Chris maybe you can answer this easily, is it better to go back to the old particle system for brownian motion or children -> kink, clumping, etc or is there a better way to produce those behaviors in GN?

Comment: @AllenSimpson: unfortunately i never tried out the new hair system...had no time ...sorry :( and if you didn't waste your time on Nodevember and upload every day a new video you would have time to try out....(that was a jooooooooke) ‍♂️

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/202061/110840

Answer (score 2):

For fluffy fur need to make the hair curly and the tips thin:

[image: fluffy fur ball]

In the old *Particle System* this can be done by setting a low number for the *Brownian* value as you can see here: [How can I make the particle systems look more like fur?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/202052/107598)

**For the new *Curves* hair in Blender 3.3**, such a setting does not exist yet. But you can add it relatively easily by *Geometry Nodes*. **Here is the *Hair Noise* modifier**, taken from the [Einar demo file](https://studio.blender.org/films/heist/gallery/?asset=6072):

[image: hair noise]

Then add another ***Geometry Nodes* modifier (*Hair thickness*)** to the *Curves* object to control the thickness. Make the roots thicker than the tips. In the example, the values `0.004` and `0.00008` are used. The modifier is shown here:  [3.3 Geo nodes, Hair Curves. How to make the thickness have a tapered tip?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/270059/107598). Also, make sure you have the **Important Setting for the Viewport and Eevee** as shown in the linked question.